# trying to check live email availability using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, forms

```
function checkAvailability() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "check_availability.php",
        data:'email='+$("#email").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
            $("#user-availability-status").html(data);
            $("#loaderIcon").hide();
        },
        error:function (){}
    });
}
```

the code is working fine.......**but if email already exist in database then form should not be submitted**...i m new to java script what to do ?

```
<?php
include('conection.php');


if(!empty($_POST["email"])) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='" . $_POST["email"]
        . "'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $user_count = $row[0];
  if($user_count>0) {
  echo "<span class='status-not-available'> Email Already 
    Registered</span>";
  }else{
  echo "<span class='status-available'> Email Available.</span>";
   }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: what is the returning data?

Comment: You need to prevent the default action of submitting the form, then do your email checking request – and based on the result of that submit the form via JS or not.